# Does the Intel SDM's "Intra-Processor Forwarding Is Allowed" memory ordering litmus test for store-forwarding show LoadLoad reordering?

Tags: x86, memory-barriers

[image]

This behavior can be represented by the following figure:
[image]

But in my opinion, this memory older violates the order of load ->load.
For Core 1, Load 1 executes after Load 2.

In [x86 memory ordering: Loads Reordered with Earlier Stores vs. Intra-Processor Forwarding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20907811/x86-memory-ordering-loads-reordered-with-earlier-stores-vs-intra-processor-for)
link, @BeeOnRope explain that this is a `store forwarding reordering`, but I don't know whether it is this a special situation TSO allowing other than  STORE->LOAD out-of-older or not.

Comment: Store-forwarding makes the store value visible to the core before it's visible to other cores.  The loads run (as if) in program order, but the value can be something that's not yet in coherent cache.  See also [Globally Invisible load instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50609934) - the effects of store forwarding aren't exactly explainable in terms of just StoreLoad or LoadLoad reordering.